# Javascript MongoDB create another unique id if exists in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, unique

I'm trying to run this function but it's returning undefined.

```
function generateshortid() {
            const myid = shortid.generate();

            Note.findOne({shortid: myid}, function(err, data) {
                if (data) {
                    const newid = shortid.generate();
                    console.log(data)
                    return newid;
                } else {console.log(myid); return myid;}
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are returning a value from a *callback*. This will not work. Why, you ask? Think about this from Mongoose's point of view. When you call `Note.findOne(condition, callback)`, you can imagine Mongoose does something like (note this is over-simplified for sake of argument):

```js
const result = collection.findOne(condition);
const note = new Note(result);
callback(null, note);
```

It calls the provided callback function and discards the result - the flow control now belongs to your callback. This is a common pattern called continuation-passing style (CPS), and Node.js APIs have used it since the beginning, though most are now transitioning to Promises and async/await, which would have simplified your code.

Assuming you need to stick to callbacks, you'll need to change the signature of your function to accept a callback, and pass the generated value to it, like so:

```js
        function generateshortid(callback) {
            const myid = shortid.generate();

            Note.findOne({shortid: myid}, function(err, data) {
                if (data) {
                    const newid = shortid.generate();
                    console.log(data)
                    callback(newid);
                } else {console.log(myid); callback(myid);}
            });
        };
```

However, there are multiple issues with this function (other than the original inability to get the return value out):

- Lack of error handling
- Invalid assumption that the second try will get a unique ID when the first one didn't

In general, I would recommend learning about callbacks vs. Promises and async/await and reconsidering your unique ID generation strategy. In the end, you may be better served by MongoDB's automatic `_id` field.